# Joins in Laravel and showing data in a view

Tags: php, laravel

How to use aliases of table use in joins in a View.I write the following join query

```
$show Data = DB::table('jobs_users')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs_users.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
        ->join('users as u1', 'jobs_users.user_id', '=', 'u1.id')
        ->join('users as t1', 'jobs_users.trainer_id', '=', 't1.id')
        ->get();
```

I have two table Jobs and users and their ids is stored in a pivot table.
In user table i have user trainer and user student. Now i want to show the name of job, student and trainer in a view. i am getting the name of job, trainer but not getting the name of student. In a view i use the join result as follows

```
@for each ($show Data as $u)
    <TD>
        {{$u->company Name}}   // job name
    </TD>
    <TD>
        {{$u ->user Name}}  //trainer name
    </TD>
    <TD>
        {{$u->user Name}}</TD>   // student name
    </tr>
@end for each
```

in La ravel 5.2
user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->null able();
        $table->integer('user_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->en um('account Type',['Fresh',                     'Professional'])->null able();
        $table->string('user Name',30);
        $table->string('email', 30)->unique();
        $table->string('password',64);
        $table->date('dob',30)->null able();
        $table->en um('gender',['Male', 'Female']);
        $table->string('country',30)->null able();
        $table->string('city',15)->null able();
        $table->string('mobile No', 15)->null able();//+92 42 5689896
        $table->string('c n i c',60)->null able();
        $table->string('address',512)->null able();
        $table->string('degree Level',30)->null able();
        $table->string('degree Title',30)->null able();
        $table->string('institution',60)->null able();
        $table->string('degree Country',60)->null able();
        $table->string('degree City',60)->null able();
        $table->string('experience')->null able();;
        $table->unsigned Small Integer('work Experience')->null able();
        $table->string('industry', 60)->null able();
        $table->string('aced Country',30)->null able();
        $table->string('c v',30)->null able();
        $table->remember Token();
        $table->time stamps();
        $table->soft Deletes();



    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your database tables too?

Answer (score 3):

Use `select()`:

```
$showData = DB::table('jobs_users')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs_users.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
        ->join('users as u1', 'jobs_users.user_id', '=', 'u1.id')
        ->join('users as t1', 'jobs_users.trainer_id', '=', 't1.id')
        ->select(<your other selects>, 'u1.name as u_name', 't1.name as t_name') //<- add your other selects
        ->get();
```

and display it in your views:

```
<td>
     {{$u->u_name}} <!--trainer name-->
</td>
<td>
     {{$u->t_name}} <!--student name-->
</td>
```

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$companyName (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bridging_the_gap\resources\views\adminspanel\admin\assigntrainer.blade.php)   i am getting this error after i tried your code

Comment: have you replaced  `<your other selects>` to your other selected attributes?

Comment: i have no other selected attributes

Comment: Thanks alot sir, I solved the problem thank u very much sir

Comment: No it is not present in jobs_users. it is present in jobs table